# If Java is a "call-by-value" language then why is this happening?

Tags: java, object, reference, pass-by-value

See the test code:

```
class Node
{
    int num = 0;
}

class TestPassByReference
{
    void increaseByOne(Node N)
    {
        N.num++ ;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Node N = new Node() ;
        TestPassByReference T  = new TestPassByReference() ;
        T.increaseByOne(N) ;
        System.out.println("num = "+N.num) ;
        T.increaseByOne(N) ;
        System.out.println("num = "+N.num) ;
        T.increaseByOne(N) ;
        System.out.println("num = "+N.num) ;
    }
}
```

Which gives the result:

```
num = 1
num = 2
num = 3
```

The problem here, is that since `Java` is `call by value` then the `num` attribute of `Node` should have remained 0.

I think that this is due to creation of an object `T`, which would have contained an object `N`. But there is no attribute in `T` to save a `Node` like object. So how is this happening?

Any help is nefariously appreciated.

Moon.

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value ?

Comment: N is Called-by-value. When you reference the value with the dot, you leave the copied value which is an object reference and reference the object. This is called pointers in other languages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Java` is call-by-value in the sense that `references` are passed-by-value.

This means you can change the internal state of the object you passed `N` (e.g. by modifying the `num` field's value) but you cannot reassign `N` to a new object (e.g. `N = null;` or `N = new Node();`).

```
class Node
{
    int num = 0;
}

class TestPassByReference
{
    void increaseByOne(Node N)
    {
        N.num++ ;
        System.out.println("num value is:" + N.num);
    }

    void increaseByOneThenChange(Node N)
    {
        // increase by one as before
        N.num++;
        // change the reference to a new object
        N = new Node();
        System.out.println("num value is:" + N.num);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Node N = new Node() ;
        TestPassByReference T  = new TestPassByReference() ;
        T.increaseByOne(N) ;
        System.out.println("num = "+N.num) ;
        T.increaseByOne(N) ;
        System.out.println("num = "+N.num) ;
        T.increaseByOne(N) ;
        System.out.println("num = "+N.num) ;

       // now try this method to see the difference
       T.increaseByOneThenChange(N);
       // N here is the original object, whose `num` value was incremented
       // but the reference remains unchanged by the above method
       System.out.println("num = "+N.num) ;
    }
}
```

In the second case, only the reference that was passed to the method changes thus being visible only in the method's body (`N` will no longer refer the original object here), but the original one remains the same.

Answer (score 4):

Java passes objects by reference. `Node N` is an object. So when you do `N.num++` you're incrementing the same object's integer.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have single Object of class Node .

That holds value of `num` with initial value 0,
And when call function and increment value of `num` each time value of `num` will be increase because same Node class object . its simple to understand node object is instance of class Node if you make another Node class object it will different instance of class .

```
class Node
{
    int num = 0;
}
class TestPassByReference
{
    void increaseByOne(Node N)
    {
        N.num++ ;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Node N1 = new Node() ;
        Node N2 = new Node() ;
        TestPassByReference T  = new TestPassByReference() ;
        T.increaseByOne(N1) ;
        System.out.println("num = "+N1.num) ;
        T.increaseByOne(N1) ;
        System.out.println("num = "+N1.num) ;
        T.increaseByOne(N2) ;
        System.out.println("num = "+N2.num) ;
    }
}
```

Then out come is :

```
num = 1
num = 2
num = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you are creating single object of Node and TestPassByReference so T referes the same Node reference which you cloud create earlier. So the same value is increaments when you call the method.